# Quasar table when using body slot, first column not visible

Tags: quasar-framework

I am using a q-table in quasar with this rows (agregates) and columns (AColumns)

```
const agregates = [
  {
    id: 0,
    label: "Recettes générales",
    debit: null,
    credit:
      getCassetteGeneralIncomesValue.value() +
      getBankGeneralIncomesValue.value(),
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    label: "Dépenses générales",
    debit:
      getCassetteGeneralExpensesValue.value() +
      getBankGeneralExpensesValue.value(),
    credit: null,
  },
];
for (let i = 0; i < eventBalances.value.length; i++) {
  agregates.push({
    id: i + 2,
    label: "Evénement :" + eventBalances.value[i].label,
    debit: eventBalances.value[i].val >= 0 ? null : eventBalances.value[i].val,
    credit: eventBalances.value[i].val >= 0 ? eventBalances.value[i].val : null,
  });
}


const AColumns = ref([
  {
    name: "label ",
    label: "Intitulé",
    field: (row) => row.label,
    align: "left",
    style: "width: 600px; background-color:'green';",
  },
  {
    name: "debit",
    label: "Debit",
    field: (row) => (typeof row.debit === "number" ? asEuros(row.debit) : null),
    align: "right",
    style: "width: 150px",
  },
  {
    name: "credit",
    label: "Credit",
    field: (row) =>
      typeof row.credit === "number" ? asEuros(row.credit) : null,
    align: "right",
    style: "width: 150px",
  },
]);
```

When I use the table basically i.e. without slot like this

```
  <div id="q-app">
    <div class="q-pa-md" style="width: 900px">
      <q-table
        title="Recettes générales"
        :rows="generalIncomes"
        :columns="AColumns"
        row-key="name"
        hide-bottom
      ></q-table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I get this
[image]

But when I try the body slot, in order to be able to customize row styles like this

```
   <div class="q-pa-md" style="width: 900px">
      <q-table
        title="Compte d'exploitation"
        :rows="agregates"
        :columns="AColumns"
        row-key="id"
        hide-bottom
      >
        <template #body="props">
          <q-tr :props="props">
            <q-td key="label" :props="props" class="text-red">
              {{ props.row.label }}</q-td
            >
            <q-td key="debit" :props="props" class="text-blue">
              {{ asEuros(props.row.debit) }}
            </q-td>
            <q-td key="credit" :props="props">
              {{ asEuros(props.row.credit) }}
            </q-td>
          </q-tr>
        </template>
      </q-table>
    </div>
```

I get this (first column of body is missing)

[image]

I don't see what is wrong !

Comment: there is extra space in name: "label ",  remove space it will work